# How to remove highlited date on datepicker

Tags: html, css, datepicker

I have a calendar I want the on-going date should be marked on the calendar  eg( blue 22th of June), and **clicking on any other date changes this selection.**

Right now everything works perfectly but when I select any date in a calendar the current date is still highlighted

Expected result when a user clicks another date the current date should not be highlighted.

**Note:** here  is the link to the live demo : https://proexebookingapp.herokuapp.com/

I am using this calendar https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

[image]

Here is what I have tried

```
.ui-datepicker.ui-widget .ui-datepicker-calendar td a.ui-state-highlight{
      display: none;

}
```

I have tried to overide css and different combination but nothing works.

What do I need to do to achieve what I want?

Comment: Is date picker activated? For now, it seems that scripts are not working at all. The source example is already have, an effect you are trying to achieve by modifying styles

Comment: datepicker is activated everything works perfect except when I click or select another date the current date is still highlited , I want when u select another date the current date(todays day) should not be highlited

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to make it on the wrong field...

Comment: is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use `onSelect` method (from the documentation: "Callback to invoke when a date is selected. Note that this event is not called when the value is entered from the input manually.") and get access to the current date by using class selector `.ui-datepicker-today`

Comment: am not so good in javascript I dont know how to do what U said, can you  show how to do it as answer if you dont mind?

Comment: It is Angularjs component. I am not familiar with this framework so I cannot create simple example to play with

Answer (score 0):

Instead of display: none, have you tried setting the background color to transparent?

```
.ui-datepicker.ui-widget .ui-datepicker-calendar td a.ui-state-highlight {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: but that will make it transparent  all the time , what I want is when I have selected another date the deafult date(current date) should not be highlited as its right now, you can check it yourself: https://proexebookingapp.herokuapp.com/